# Getting a 204 No Content response when I use restSetResponse in Coldfusion 10 REST

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to use restSetResponse to set my own status and content as described in the docs here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-5719eac51353e6bb244-7fec.html

Here is my REST method:

```
remote any function test() httpmethod="get" {
    var response = {
        status: 400,
        content: 'something is wrong'
    };
    restSetResponse(response);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've set `returntype` to any instead of void and you have no `produces` attribute?

Comment: Ooooh, now I get it. If I want to return custom responses, I have to control all the responses that are possible. The method has to have 'returntype' void, like you pointed out. If I want to respond with 200 in a successful case in the same method, then I have to handle that myself. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [link you provided](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-5719eac51353e6bb244-7fec.html), note the first numbered bullet under the "**Send custom success responses using restSetResponse**" heading.  If you define the CFC as REST service, you need to ensure the returnType is set to "**void**".  In your example, you have your returnType set to "**any**".

Comment: Yes. For some reason, I really thought that `any` encompassed `void` as well. I also didn't understand how to return content in the success case, since the `returntype` was `void`, but I now get that if I use `restSetResponse`, I have to set the status and content and use `restSetResponse` for every possible case.